# Javascript CRUD Admin for Spring-Data HATEOAS backend

Tags: spring-data, jhipster, hateoas, ng-admin, lightadmin

We are using a Spring-Boot Spring-Data backend that utilizes JPARepositories with the `@RepositoryRestResource` annotation.  We would like to administer the tables in these repositories (e.g. CRUD) through a javascript frontend without having to go through the work of coding it up.  We investigated various alternatives such as LightAdmin, JHipster and ng-admin.

We could not get LightAdmin to work because it relies on a much older version of Spring-Data than what we are running.  It is not compatible with the latest and greatest Spring-Data release.

We tried JHipster, but it scaffolds up all the services and controllers which we do not want because @RepositoryRestResource gives that to you for free.

We tried to use ng-admin, but it does not work to well in the context of HATEOAS; we had to put in far too many mappings to get it to only partially work.

So my question is this.  Is there a product out that that is similar to ng-admin, JHipster and LightAdmin that will allow us to easily CRUD our `@RepositoryRestResource` JPA repositories such that we don't have to write boilerplate CRUD code?

Comment: what did you finally choose for CRUD admin?

Answer (score -1):

```
may be you can use my awesome code :


db.js 

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose()
const db = new sqlite3.Database("./book.db")

module.exports = db

setup.js

const db = require("./db.js")

const query = [
    `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    contacts (
        contactID  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT,
        company TEXT,
        telephone TEXT,
        email TEXT UNIQUE
    )`,
    `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    groups (
        groupID  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        name TEXT
    )`,
    `
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
    group_contacts (
        group_contactsID  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
        contactID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        groupID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY(contactID) REFERENCES contacts(contactID),
        FOREIGN KEY(groupID) REFERENCES groups(groupID)

    )`
]

for (let i = 0; i < query.length; i++){
    db.run(query[i], (err) =>{
        console.log(err)
    })
}

index.js

const controller = require("./controller.js")
let input = process.argv.slice(2)
let cmd = input[0]
let data = input.slice(1)

switch(cmd){
    case "createContact":
    controller.createContact(data)
    break

controller.js

const contact = require("./model/contact.js")
const group = require("./model/group.js")
const groupContact = require("./model/contact-group.js")
const view = require("./view.js")
class Controller{
    static createContact(data){
        contact.create(data, (err, output) => {
            if (err){
                view.createError(err)
            } else {
                view.createSuccess(output)
            }
        })
    }
    static readContact(data){
        contact.read(data, (err, output) => {
            if (err){
                view.readError(err)
            } else {
                view.readSuccess(output)
            }
        })  
    }
    static updateContact(data){
        contact.update(data, (err) => {
            if (err){
                view.updateError(err)
            } else {
                view.updateSuccess(data)
            }
        })
    }
    static deleteContact(data){
        contact.delete(data, (err) => {
            if (err){
                view.deleteError(err)
            } else {
                view.deleteSuccess(data[0])
            }
        })
    }
}
module.exports = Controller

model.js

const db = require("../db.js")
class Contact{
    constructor(name, company, phone, email){
        this.name = name
        this.company = company
        this.telephone = phone
        this.email = email
    }
    static create(data, cb){
        db.serialize((err) => {
            if (err){
                cb(err, null)
            } else {
                let newContact = new Contact(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3])
                let query = `
                INSERT INTO contacts (name, company, telephone, email) 
                VALUES ('${data[0]}', '${data[1]}', '${data[2]}', '${data[3]}')`
                db.run(query, (err) => {
                    if (err){
                        cb(err, null)
                    } else {
                        cb(null, newContact)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
    static update(data, cb){
        db.serialize((err) => {
            if (err){
                cb(err, null)
            } else {
                let query = `
                UPDATE contacts SET ${data[1]} = '${data[2]}' WHERE contactID = ${data[0]}`
                db.get(query, (err) => {
                    if (err){
                        cb(err)
                    } else {
                        cb(null)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
    static read(data, cb){
        db.serialize((err) => {
            if (err){
                cb(err, null)
            } else {
                let query = `
                SELECT contactID, name, company, telephone, email FROM contacts WHERE contactID = ${data[0]}`
                db.get(query, (err, result) => {
                    if (err){
                        cb(err, null)
                    } else {
                        cb(null, result)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
    static delete(data, cb){
        db.serialize((err) => {
            if (err){
                cb(err, null)
            } else {
                let query = `
                DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contactID = ${data[0]}`
                db.get(query, (err) => {
                    if (err){
                        cb(err)
                    } else {
                        cb(null)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Contact

view.js


class View {
    static createError(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log('=====> ERROR')
    }
    static createSuccess(output){
        console.log(output)
        console.log('=====> SUCCESS')
    }
    static readError(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log('=====> ERROR')
    }
    static readSuccess(output){
        console.log(output)
        console.log('=====> SUCCESS')
    }
    static updateError(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log('=====> ERROR')
    }
    static updateSuccess(output){
        console.log(output)
        console.log('=====> SUCCESS')
    }
    static deleteError(err){
        console.log(err)
        console.log('=====> ERROR')
    }
    static deleteSuccess(output){
        console.log(output)
        console.log('=====> SUCCESS')
    }
    static undefined(output){
        console.log(output)
        console.log('=====> UNDEFINED')
    }

}

module.exports = View
```

Comment: You should [edit] your answer to include some explanation or context as to how this answers the question. A giant code block isn't immediately useful to those who might come across the same issue later on.